# Safest way to get a date from Sharepoint into a C# datetime field, using object model?

Tags: development, splistitem, date-time

If I have a Sharepoint list item with a date field.

How can I get the field value populated into a c# datetime object?

For example:

```
DateTime validfrom = Convert.ToDateTime(item["validfrom"]);
```

Although this won't produce a design time error. I am sure that this will cause problems depending on which server the code runs on and the locale settings for the server.

Is there a foolproof way to get the c# object populated?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use one of the [SPUtility.ParseDate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.parsedate.aspx) overloads.

Check the article [Converting Date and Time Values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms197282.aspx) for more details.

Comment: +1 for link to good article on date time

Answer (score 8):

Assuming the field type of "validfrom" is  DateTime then there should be no need to convert the value, only cast it. You only need to convert/parse if your field type is text, in which case you may consider switching your type to a DateTime or use Marek's advice for conversion.

```
DateTime validFrom = (DateTime) item["validfrom"];
```

Comment: Instead of unnecessarily throwing/catching an exception (which can be considered poor dev practice by some), use the DateTime.TryParse() method instead: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1.aspx - remembering to pass item["validfrom"].ToString()l

Comment: @James The try catch is more there to check for a null reference exception. Passing a null value from item["validfrom"] to TryParse will still result in an exception. TryParse will only prevent throwing an invalid format exception.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't word my post clearly, but my point is if your field type is a DateTime there is no need to convert or parse the field value, only cast. The OP stated "I have a Sharepoint list item with a date field." I interpreted that to mean the field type was a date, not text.

Comment: Gotcha. +1 on your way.

Comment: If uninitilized it would be null, so a null check would suffice. Try/catches are relative expensive and likely to introduce bugs if you dont know exactly what you catch.