# how to display data from sharepoint list using object model in mm dd yyyy

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-server

In SharePoint 2010

List "Employee", Colum Name "JoinDate" 
has stored data in  (01/31/2014 12.00 PM) mm\dd\yyyy hr:mm PM format.

How to display this data in mm\dd\yyyy only using C# on custom web part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try following:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(oListItem["JoinDate"].ToString()
dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

[Safest way to get a date from Sharepoint into a C# datetime field, using object model?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/12820/safest-way-to-get-a-date-from-sharepoint-into-a-c-datetime-field-using-object)

Comment: I tried above code in console application but its showing date with time however I want to show only time in mm/dd/yyyy format. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround is create new column and use that column in your code.

- Create a new calculated column for your list (single line of text)
- Use the following formula to calculate its value

  =TEXT(Created,"dd mmm yy")

Use the new column to display in your list.
http://www.sharepointusecases.com/2009/01/customizing-datetime-format-on-a-list-view-web-part/

or

```
//Write the code to read your list item
SPListItem item = list.Items[0];
//Get a DateTime object with the list column value
DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(item["Date Column Name"]);

String strDate = date.ToString("dd-mmm-yyyy");
//you can also try ("dd/mmm/yyyy")
```

Comment: Thanks Waqas Sarwar, Your code work perfectly in my console application. Thanks so much.

Comment: if it solve the issue, please mark the anwser/vote so that community can get benefit from it.